# Why is one minute of angle very close to 1" at 100 yards?

Tags: trigonometry

In the shooting sports, a very common measurement is 1 minute of angle measured at 100 yards, a very common distance to shoot a rifle. If we take the tangent of 1/60 (one minute), multiply by 100 yards, and divide by 36 (to convert from yards to inches), we get:

1.047197580733"

I was just wondering if there's something "magical" about this number, in that it is very close to 1 inch, or is that mere coincidence?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $100$ yards is $3600$ inches and one minute is $\frac {2\pi}{60\times 360}$ radians. Estimating $2\pi =6$ this comes out at approx $\frac 1{3600}$ radian. For small $\theta$ measured in radians we have $\tan \theta \approx \theta$.

Expect error from estimate $\pi\approx 3$ to be of the order of $4.7\%$ (true angle is bigger)

Comment: Pardon my slowness. I see that your 4.7% might correlate to the .047..." in my result. Is that your point? Are you saying that what comes after my decimal point is error? Is 1 MOA at 100 yards actually precisely 1 inch?

Comment: @birdus Exactly right - that's where the 0.047 comes from. The angle is so small that the error from swapping $\tan \theta$ and $\theta$ is even smaller than this.

Comment: So, just to be clear, punching my equation into a perfect calculator would yield precisely 1 inch? I thought modern calculators would do better than that! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @birdus - no it will give $1.047$ inches - the estimate gives $1$ inch

Comment: Ah. Then I guess I misunderstood. So, 1 MOA at 100 yards is NOT 1 inch.

Comment: The truth is that I am probably no less confused than before. I don't really understand why we're talking about errors and estimating pi, etc.

Comment: @birdus - The one inch rule is an estimate, which is equivalent to estimating $\pi = 3$ - the initial version of this answer was inaccurate about that. The true distance is $1.047$ inches.

Comment: Okay. So I will take away, then, that there is nothing special about 1 MOA being very close to 1 inch at 100 yards. It's merely a convenient coincidence. Thanks!

Comment: @mark-bennet Technically I agree with the above, but it might be a slightly misleading way to put it. Rather, the fundamental conincidence in play here is that between: 1. the MOA angular unit, and 2. having 36 inches in a yard. It so happens that the former, if approximating _pi_ to _3_, is the inverse of the latter times 100. The fundamental "arbitrary" historic choices involved are: A.) the 36 inches/yard, B.) dividing a circle in 360 units (degrees), and C.) dividing one degree in 60 units (arcminutes). The interplay between 36, 360, 60 and _pi_ creates the "coincidence".

Comment: One way to see the "coincidence" of this approximation being possible is as the alignment between both 1. the choices of 36 inches/yard and dividing the circle in 360 units, and 2. the choice of dividing a degree in 60 units and _2*pi_ = approx. 6.29. Historically, there is almost certainly no connection between the coincidences within neither 1. nor 2. We have 360 from Babylonian astronomy, and 36 from Britain. We have 60 from _the sexagesimal system_ (a base-60 numerical system - the Babylonians again). The choice of the 60 as base is unlikely to be connected to something related to pi.

Answer (score 0):

**It is a coincidence of the involved units.**

More specifically, it is a coincidence of the combination of:

1. the angular unit *minutes of angle*, or *MOA*

   - which is $\frac{1}{60} \times \frac{2\pi}{360}$ $\approx 0.000291\ \mathrm{rad}$
2. the *number of inches in 1 yard*

   - which is $36$
   - whose inverse is $\frac{1}{36} \approx 0.0278$

You can already see the similarity between those two to decimal numbers, less a factor of $100$ (that's the $100$ yards).

For the angle $1$ MOA, its projected length $l$ at a distance of $100\ \mathrm{yd}$ is
$$
\begin{align}
l & = \tan{\left(\frac{1}{60} \times \frac{2\pi}{360}\right)} \times 100\ [\mathrm{yd}] \times 36\ [\mathrm{in}/\mathrm{yd}] \\
& \approx 1.047\ [\mathrm{in}]
\end{align}
$$

Note that the formula above is exactly the calculation you described that you did.

Whatever comes out of this expression must be a consequence of its constituents, and its constituents are the two unitless constants listed under points 1 and 2 above (and the 100 yards). Since a seemingly coincidental result, $\approx 1$ inch, does come out, such a coincidence must be a consequence of the two constants.

---

...*almost*: Under 1. above, I gave the constant $\frac{1}{60} \times \frac{2\pi}{360}$, but the formula used *the tangent* of that constant. Well, the two values only differ at the 8th decimal place, since $\tan{x} \approx x$ for small values of $x$, provided that the angle is measured in *radians*. That's *[the Small-angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation)*.

Using that approximation and decimal values, we can rewrite the expression for $l$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
l & = 0.000291\ \times 100\ [\mathrm{yd}]\ \times \frac{1}{0.0278}\ [\mathrm{in}/\mathrm{yd}] \\
& = \left( 0.0291\ \times \frac{1}{0.0278}\ \right) [\mathrm{in}] \\
& \approx 1.047\ [\mathrm{in}]
\end{align}
$$

From the intermediate expression we can see that the result will come out close to 1.

---

For this coincidental conveience, shooters can thank *the Babylonians* for the *MOA* angular unit, the *British Impreium* for the choice of *number of inches per yards*, and *God* for the *Small-angle approximation*.